# Displaying Databases in DSN SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to extract data from an SQL server that our information system uses. An old employee set up our DSN and its connection to a MS Access file that displays our schedule. I was able to find the DSN it was pulling data from and added the connection to my own computer. I can seemingly connect to the server using **osql** and entering the credentials but any queries to view databases or anything at all results in nothing. Here is what I see:

```
C: USER>osql -S SQLSERVER -U Usernmae -P Password
1>
```

I have tried a couple of methods for viewing the databases but am not sure if I am executing the commands correctly.

```
C: USER>osql -S SQLSERVER -U Usernmae -P Password
1>show databases
2>SELECT name FROM sys.sysdatabases
3>
```

I can see all the visible databases using **osql -L** but the one I am looking for is not there so I do not know if it is hidden, does not exist, or is not actually connected.

Comment: USE MASTER before select?

Comment: Perhaps your user doesn't have access to the one you are looking for?